# WebView doesn't load my HTML String in iPhone

Tags: iphone, html

This doesn't load my HTML string in the WebView.

```
NSString *htmlString = @"<html><body><h1>My First Heading</h1><p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>";
//I have a very large HTML content here.. For sample I have given a small content       
[teaserWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Do I need to use some encoding? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does your webview look like a white area? I mean, it could be that it's not displayed in your current view.

Comment: Yes my webview looks like a white area..

Comment: Finally got it.. Thanks to Nick.. I was loading the webview in another view.. Silly mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: Solution found in comments on question.**

<strike>In your large HTML, Replace `%` with `%25`.</strike>

I really don't know if that will help, but it is required in Android WebView. All encoding is automatic except it does not know whether or not to encode `%`.

There is a better way to encode everything, but it is not required and I have no clue how to do it in iPhone.

See this page for more info: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp

Also you may want to look up "URL Encode iPhone".

I know this is not a URL, but in Android it gets converted to a `data:` URL where all the data is in the URL. It likely works the same way in iPhone.

Comment: I also tried the simple html i have specified in the question still it doesnt load my string in webview.. Any idea?

Comment: Oh, I though you might have not tested the short HTML. Try an example data URL shown here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme. If that works as your string, then you need to convert a string to a data URL. (look under Examples section) (any example, even image should do) @BuildSucceeded